# Woocommerce 2.5: Hide Shipping Methods when free shipping is available not working anymore

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I Had this code

```
 /* !Hide Shipping Options Woocommerce */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'hide_shipping_based_on_tag' ,    10, 1 );

function check_cart_for_share() {

// load the contents of the cart into an array.
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;

$found = false;

// loop through the array looking for the tag you set. Switch to true if the tag is found.
foreach ($cart as $array_item) {
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $array_item['product_id'], 'product_tag', array( "fields" => "names" ) );

    if (in_array("Heavy",$term_list)) { // Replace "Heavy" with what ever tag you want

        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

return $found;

}

function hide_shipping_based_on_tag( $available_methods ) {

// use the function above to check the cart for the tag.
if ( check_cart_for_share() ) {

    // remove the rate you want
    unset( $available_methods['flat_rate'] ); // Replace "flat_rate" with the shipping option that you want to remove.
}

// return the available methods without the one you unset.
return $available_methods;

}
```

in my function.php - but since woocommerce 2.5 it's not working anymore. 
The other shipping methods need to be hidden when free shipping is available.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a hook that was used for WooCommerce version 2.1 and below.

Instead, use the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter..

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfect for latest woocommerce :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 10, 2 );

function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {

    // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {

        // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
        unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );

        // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
        $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates                  = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

I have unset the flat shipping, you can unset other shipping methods if you enabled. This code works fine for me, i tried it yesterday.